# Ionic 3 not showing camera FILE_URI path in image src

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, angular5

here is my HTML code

```
<img [src]="profileImage"/>
<button (click)="openCamera()"> Upload </button>
```

below is my component code

```
import { ViewController, Platform, normalizeURL } from 'ionic-angular';

openCamera() {
let options = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
    targetWidth: 400,
    targetHeight: 400,
    allowEdit: false
}

 this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
    this.cropService.crop(imageData, { quality: 100 }).then((newImage) => {
        this.profileImage = normalizeURL(newImage);
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("Error cropping image", error);
    });
}, (err) => {
    console.log('Error camera image', err);
});
}
```

1. while i capture image from Camera, at that time it will return FILE_URI, LIKE this **file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.exchangeconnect.sancial/cache/1536751062113-cropped.jpg?1536751088363**,
2. but image not showing in `<img>` tag

Comment: Can you check this, `import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';`.Try with `<img [src]="DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imgURI)"/>`

Comment: Which platform are you using?

Comment: @Madhavan.V i already tried this, but did't work.

Comment: @SandipLipane i'm using android platform.

Comment: @BhavinShiroya, Please try below given solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code. Please find updated code below:

```
import { ViewController, Platform, normalizeURL } from 'ionic-angular';

openCamera() {
    let options = {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
        targetWidth: 400,
        targetHeight: 400,
        allowEdit: false
    }

     this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
        this.cropService.crop(imageData, { quality: 100 }).then((newImage) => {
            if (this.platform.is('ios')){
                this.profileImage = normalizeURL(newImage);
            }else{
                this.profileImage= "data:image/jpeg;base64," + newImage;
            }
        }, (error) => {
            console.log("Error cropping image", error);
        });
    }, (err) => {
        console.log('Error camera image', err);
    });
}
```

Or
If above solution is not working then please try below code:

```
    import { ViewController, Platform, normalizeURL } from 'ionic-angular';

    openCamera() {
      let options = {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
        targetWidth: 400,
        targetHeight: 400,
        allowEdit: false
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
          // don't need to crop image for iOS platform as it is a in-build feature
          if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
            this.getFileUri(imageData);
          }else { // android platform, we need to do manually
            this.cropService.crop(imageData, { quality: 100 }).then(newImage => {
                this.getFileUri(newImage);
              },
              error => console.error('Error cropping image', error)
            );
         }
    }, (err) => {
        console.log('Error camera image', err);
    });
}

private getFileUri = (url: any) => {
    var scope = this;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        scope.profileImage = reader.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
}
```

I think its related to "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" plugin. Please refer below steps to overcome the issue:
1] uninstall existing webview plugin

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
```

2] install old version

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@1.2.1
```

3] clean cordova android

```
ionic cordova clean android
```

Please find more details here https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/158

Comment: @Bhavin Shiroya, I have updated the answer, please check the same.

Comment: i got this two error like this "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.exchangeconnect.sancial/cache/1537447078582-cropped.jpg?1537447081663.
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, https."

Comment: and second one is "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.exchangeconnect.sancial/cache/1537447078582-cropped.jpg?1537447081663"

Comment: I think its related to "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" plugin. BTW may I know your ionic version?

Comment: i am using  "ionic-angular": "3.9.2", and "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.1.4"

Comment: @Bhavin Shiroya, Updated the answer

Comment: i tried your last updated code but not wroking, got this error

 "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at e.get [as convertFileSrc] (vendor.js:1)
    at main.js:1
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:1)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:1)"

Comment: I am using same code and here it is working for both android and IOS platforms

Comment: please tell me your package version of "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" and "@ionic-native/ionic-webview"

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving your original code and change

```
saveToPhotoAlbum: false
```

to

```
saveToPhotoAlbum: true
```